# extract values from jdbc exception

Tags: java, exception, jdbc, oracle11g

Are there any library for oracle exception message parsing?

For example I get following exception during query execution http://ora-12899.ora-code.com/ I need to extract column name (without table name). I could do that with regular expressions, but that seems to be very fragile as message may depend on client locale and also it could change when oracle version changes.

Are there any better solution?

Comment: Outside of SQLException.getMessage() I think the useful built in stuff is limited to getSQLState(), getErrorCode() and the list of causes from the stack trace(getCause()). You might be able to use the getErrorCode() call to figure out when you would be interested in using a regex on the message for the column name. It's not a great solution but I don't know of any existing library to parse SQLExceptions to the level of detail you're after. Seems like something that would be useful though.